# Help with different formulas for Gibbs free energy

Tags: energy, work, entropy, reversibility, chemical-potential

I am very confused with the following concepts:

> - Gibbs free energy tells us about the chemical energy of our systems!
>   $$dG=\sum_i\mu_idn_i\qquad\qquad\qquad G=\sum_i\mu_in_i$$
> - All chemical systems will try and minimise the Gibbs free energy
>   $$(dG)_{p,T}=dQ-TdS\le0$$

I don't really see the relation between both expressions for $dG$. First I thought that

$$(dG)_{p,T} = \delta Q-TdS$$

could only be obtained if the number of moles $n$ is kept constant and with constant $T$ and $P$. Correct me if I'm wrong in this please.

But then I don't understand the following: If no matter is added or taken away from a system, according to

$$dG = \sum_i\mu_idn_i$$

since $dn_i= 0$, $dG= 0$

But then, does this mean (substituting $dG= 0$ in the last equation) that

$$\delta Q = TdS$$

? So according to this, all processes in which matter is not added or taken away from a system are reversible processes ($dG= 0$). Is this correct?

I'm really confused with these concepts and the different equations for $G$ and $dG$. I saw that the first could be obtained from "Euler's Integration" and the last one from the 2º Law. But I am struggling with these concepts and I would really appreciate an explanation. Also, we just started studying this in university so I don't know a lot about this subject.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Consider the chemical reaction: $$CH_{4}+2O_{2}\leftrightarrows CO_{2}+2H_{2}O$$ close to equilibrium. Closed system (no matter added). But $$dn_{CH_{4}}+2dn_{O_{2}}-dn_{CO_{2}}-2dn_{H_{2}O}=0$$ so that, $$dn=\sum_{i}dn_{i}=0$$ And yet, $$dn_{i}\neq0$$. Could that be part of the reason for your confusion?

Comment: And one more thing. Why is this true?: (),=− ≤ 0.  I know that if you apply the Clausius inequality you get this. However, some years ago, in chemistry, we did do exercises where delta G was positive and this would mean that the reaction wasn't spontaneous. So this confuses me. Why can't dG be defined for non spontaneous reactions? Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Ohhhh. Yes I think so. Because then, my summation of ∑u wouldn't necessarily need to be zero right? So then dG can be negative

Comment: And I read that chemical potential is the work needed to introduce a mole of that substance in a system under given pressure and temperature conditions . Then does it even make sense to talk about chemical potential in closed systems ??